# How can I make a local only bridged interface using the IP utility for SNORT?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, snort

I am trying to use the Snort IPS. In order to use it as an inline prevention system I need to make two interfaces and snort will bridge the two to apply its rules as a packet passes through the bridge. My issue however comes when I actually make a bridge between the interfaces. I have to make another virtual interface to bridge with my physical one and I have been using the dummy interface option of the ip command to do this, but I don't know if that's the right way to make a usable virtual interface. However, when I do this and bridge the two outside of snort to test connectivity, I lose all connection to the external network. Here's what Ive tried:

```
sudo ip link add name eth1 type dummy
sudo ip link add name br0 type bridge
sudo ip link set wlp0s20f3 master br0
sudo ip link set eth1 master br0
```

After this, I assign them all unclaimed ip addresses and mac addresses then bring them all up

```
sudo ip link set dev eth1 up
sudo ip link set dev br0 up
```

Full disclosure, I've never done networking on Linux and will take any assistance you could give, even if I have to do this completely differently.

Comment: It really requires a bridge? It should be able to work in "mirror" mode, where the switch is set to mirror everything towards some port, where the snort sensor is connected? // That said, why won't you make a bridge with the single member? Just create a bridge and enslave an interface into it. There is no need for second "virtual" interface.

Comment: Whoa! I hadn't thought of that, let me give it a shot right now. From what I had read from the snort docs, I would need two interfaces to operate in inline mode but let me see what I can dig up with mirror <3